# android google maps app running on galaxy s, but not on galaxy tab - getting grey tiles

Tags: android, google-maps

i have developed an android application using google maps. when i deploy the application to a samsung galaxy s handset (runnning on Android 2.1) and also on other handsets running on Android 2.1 everything works fine.
when i change my project to support Android 2.2 i can still deploy the application to the galaxy tablet  (running on Android 2.2). all functionality works there like on the galaxy s (Android 2.1) except the maps integration. when i open the maps on the android 2.2 device i only get grey tiles.

thanks in advance for your help.

br,
martin

Answer (score 2):

This is usually due to wrong Maps API key. Are you exporting as debug to one and release to the other?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new map API key for android 2.2 galaxy tablet.